# Relational model - Origin and Destination City

Tags: hibernate, relational-database, mysql-workbench

Hi i need help with a model i'm working on. Departure (salida) must have a origin city and could have many destination cities. How can i deploy that in the model without making a redundant entitie like in the image? I'm working with Hibernate mapping and i need Salida entitie to have a field City for de origin city, and a list of City for the destination. How can i achieve that?

[image: workbench partial model image]

Comment: Why have CIUDADES_DESTINO at all.  A city is a city, it's role depends on whether it's an origin or destination.  SALIDAS is a schedule.  By creating CIUDADES (master list of origin and destinations), SALIDAS (or VIAJES) and SEGMENTO to describe a given travel segment that contains CIUDAD_DE_ORIGEN and CIUDAD_DESTINO, you have covered all of them.  All you would need to do is add something that describes how the SEGMENTOs are ordered (dates and times would work) and you have your travel itinerary.

Comment: Think of it this way - you have a bunch of cities.  You have travel schedules (which is nothing more than a template of legs or "segmentos").  Then you have the actual travel itinerary.